# 'unmet deficines' error on linux terminal

Tags: updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to download gnucobol for a class and I cannot get it to work. I've tried a few things from this forum (install -f etc) but still no luck :( I have just begun learning to use terminals/ubuntu etc.

Here is what I get:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install gnucobol
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcob5-dev : Breaks: libcob4-dev but 3.1.2-5 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

First run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade` to apply all the available upgrades.

Then, remove `libcob5-dev` with `sudo apt remove --autoremove libcob5-dev`.

Then install the Cobol compiler with `sudo apt-get install gnucobol`